# Why is my guest user changing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

I am building a survey with angularjs and rails 5. I cannot keep identifying information, so I am creating a guest user instead of using standard auth methods. I successfully created a guest user, however the guest user changes (creates a new guest) with each response answered. I want to be able to track the guest user's response to each question. Any suggestions on how to make the guest user persist throughout the session? NOTE: I am NOT using Devise.

Here is my application controller:

```
  def current_or_guest_user
   if current_user
    if session[:guest_user_id] && session[:guest_user_id] != current_user.id
     guest_user(with_retry = false).try(:destroy)
     session[:guest_user_id] = nil
    end
    current_user
   else
    guest_user
 end 
end

def guest_user(with_retry = true)
# Cache the value the first time it's gotten.
  @cached_guest_user ||= User.find(session[:guest_user_id] ||= create_guest_user.id)

rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound # if session[:guest_user_id] invalid
  session[:guest_user_id] = nil
guest_user if with_retry
end

private

def create_guest_user
 u = User.create(:email => "guest_#{Time.now.to_i}#{rand(100)}@example.com", ip: ip)
 u.save!(:validate => false)
 session[:guest_user_id] = u.id
 u
```

end

And here is my response controller:

```
  def create
 # @response = Response.new(response_params)
  @response = current_or_guest_user.responses.build(response_params)

   if @response.save
    render json: @response, status: :created, location: @response
   else
    render json: @response.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
 end
```

end